# How to add a fragment to an Activity without a container

Tags: android

Is that possible I can add a fragment view on the activity view without specifying "fragment" view component in activity's layout xml file? Which function should I look for?

Comment: How come @CommonsWare's answer not answer you question? What exactly you need to know?

Comment: Any potential solution to add fragment without a container, even it wont will ( I can tolerate configuration change issue mentioned in that answer)

Comment: @ywj7931 you could add the fragment directly in xml layout, without a container. If that works in your case, I can write an answer. Or you want to add fragment in code without anything at xml?

Comment: @EduardoHerzer yes, i am looking for solution of adding fragment in code without anything at xml, thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Well, the UI of the fragment has to go *somewhere*. If you want the entire "content view" to be the fragment, add the fragment to `android.R.id.content`:

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content)==null) {
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, new ToDoRosterListFragment())
        .commit();
    }
  }
```

Otherwise, somewhere in the activity's view hierarchy, you need a container (usually a `FrameLayout`) in which to place the fragment's UI. Typically, we do that by putting the container in the layout resource.

Comment: Is it possible to add the container programmatically at run time?

Comment: @ywj7931: I do not think that will work well, given that Android wants to recreate the fragment on a configuration change (e.g., orientation change).

Comment: @ywj7931, yes, it's possible. To do that you have to add a container view to the activity layout at runtime and after this do the fragment transaction with the newly added view at runtime.

Comment: this overlaps the view from the activity from the view of the fragment, how can I prevent that?

Comment: @Andrea: Set up a separate container. In your activity layout, put a `<FrameLayout>` where you want your fragment to go. Give that `FrameLayout` an `android:id` value, and use that value in your `add()` call on the `FragmentTransaction`. See the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: This solution was working for me previously but now my fragment is being overlapped by the status bar. I've tried adding `fitsSystemWindows` but to no avail. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: @masterwok: You might want to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, with a [mcve] that shows your code and what visual effect you are getting.

Comment: Solution for views overlapping: use a background color for your fragment layout. For me worked.

Answer (score 11):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, MyFragment.newInstance())
            .commit();

   //Some of your code here
}
```

`android.R.id.content` is the container of entire app screen.
It can be used with Fragment:

The `android.R.id.content` ID value indicates the ViewGroup of the entire content area of an Activity.

The code above will insert the View created by Fragment into the ViewGroup identified by `android.R.id.content`.

Comment: this overlaps the view from the activity from the view of the fragment... how can I prevent that?

Answer (score 4):

Simply, while creating a fragment we have to replace or add fragment's view with a view present in our application. To replace or add a fragment's, we normally add a Framelayout or any other layout view(as a fragmentview container) in activity or in a fragment.

Now, If you want to replace or add a fragment's view without adding a extra view container in your activity. You can simply do it by accessing the view's provided by `AppCompatActivity` or `Activity`.

Now, you can create a fragment, without adding a view container in your activity you can create as,

```
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);  //here, android.R.id.content is a view on which your fragment's view is replaced
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a layout in your activity to contain the fragment (preferably a FrameLayout).

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:name="com.gdevelopers.movies.movies.FragmentMoreMovies"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Then in activity put this code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, new YourFragment())
    .commit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to go with @CommonsWare answer, then you'll have to provide a container by code. then function you need is....

```
setContentView(View)
```

Yep. If you check the activity class code, you'll see that setContentView can be called with an INT (layouts are identified with ints), or with Views. Therefore, you can create a viewgroup instance on the fly, keep a reference to it (you would need to do the same with an XML generated view), and add your fragments there. This is possible because XML files are just arguments which the view factory class, Inflater, uses to find which view subclasses has to instantiate, using a set of parameters provided in the XML. And obviously, you can do that by hand. Just pick whatever layout class you want to use, for example, FrameLayout, and:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity{

private FrameLayout root;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    root = new FrameLayout(this); 
 root.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    setContentView(root);
//go on
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

use android container instead of custom container like

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content,yourFragment);
```

Answer (score 2):

1.use `getWindow().getDecorView()` to get a `DecorView`(`FramLayout`)
2.add a container view to `DecorView`
3.add `Fragment` to the container view

Answer (score 2):

```
LinearLayout llRoot = findViewById(R.id.parent);

FragmentManager fragMan = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragMan.beginTransaction();
YourFragment yourFragment = (YourFragment)fragMan.findFragmentByTag("yourFragment");
if (yourFragment == null) {
  yourFragment = new YourFragment();
}
fragTransaction.replace(llRoot.getId(), yourFragment, "yourFragment");
fragTransaction.commit();
```

llRoot is a LinearLayout which contains different view object of your  activity

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to allocate a specific place in the view to the fragment container you can always use the `RelativeLayour`. I guess without a container we cant place a fragment in a view.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any `View` or say root view from the activity window, get its Id using `view.getId()` (relevant to `android:id`) and pass that id to the `fragmentTransaction.add()` as the container id. Here's just a sample:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View view = new View(this);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(view.getId(), new Fragment());
}
```